# Unable to login after manual edit of /etc/passwd

Tags: raspberry-pi, root, chmod, transmission

Had a trouble with transmission daemon's permission. It keeps using default `debian-transmission` even after editing `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon`. So I edited the `/etc/passwd` and set `0:0` to `debian-transmission`. And now I can't login to the pi.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: "set `0:0` to `debian-transmission`" – Do you mean there's no `root` in `/etc/passwd` anymore? Or there's `root` and `debian-transmission` and they both have `0:0` associated? – "I can't login" – Directly or via SSH, or how? As `root` or `debian-transmission`, or another user? Was the OS rebooted afterwards or not? Is there a login prompt at all? Any error message?

Comment: Can you show us the `debian-transmission` line in you /etc/password. Can you details what you mean by "I can't login". Is it regardless the user ?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski there was a root on the top. Now they both `0:0`. Both. Can't login via SSH or directly. It keeps saying password is incorrect. Yes OS was rebooted one time. Also no error message.

Comment: @vera Can't show it to you because can't login to the pi. It keeps saying password is incorrect.

Comment: Do you try logging with debian-transmission user ?

Comment: @vera also changed debian-transmission to `0:0`. So can't login either.

Comment: Ok. In fact, setting the same UID to multiple user is equal to set set another user name (`debian-transmission`) to the first user with this UID (`root`). Then when you try connecting with `debian-transmission` user use the root password. You will then be able to log in

Comment: @vera Problem solved. Adding `init=/bin/sh` in the `cmdline.txt` makes pi start as single user mode so that you can change the user passwords.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `init=/bin/sh` in the `cmdline.txt` makes pi start as single user mode so that you can change the user password.

Comment: This won't work for me.

Comment: To add to this, I got it working, but no one has made it clear that it doesn't go on a new line. It should simply go on the end of the first line with just a space separating the last command. This worked.